# What is the build process for setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Execution of `pip install <python-package>` goes through two prominent stages:

1. `Running setup.py egg_info for package <python-package>`
2. `Running setup.py install for <python-package>`

What does actually happen behind-the-scenes in the stages above?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819492/how-does-python-setuptools-work